# What kind of activity do the long candle-lines on candlestick charts correspond to?

Tags: technical-analysis, chart

The image at the bottom shows the price of a particular stock earlier today on a red/green candlestick chart.

Some of the candle bodies have thin lines ,circled in red, sticking up (circled on one candle) and down (circled on another candle). There are also cases where the body and the lines are red instead of green.

**The questions I wanted to ask:**

1. What kind of activity do the long candle-lines upward and downward
   from **green** candles correspond to?
2. What kind of activity do the long candle-lines upward and downward
   from **red** candles correspond to?

[image: candlestick chart]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "fat" part of the candlestick represents the beginning and ending prices. If the end price is higher than the beginning price the stick will be colored green. If the end price is below the beginning price the stick will be colored red.  Typically green sticks are hollow and red are filled in so that up and down movements can be distinguished when shown in black-and-white (or for the color blind)

The "wicks" represent the high and low prices *during the period*

So the wick at the bottom shows trades that were made below the open (or close) price, and the wick at the top represents the trades that were made above the closer (or open) price.

Comment: @D Stanley Nice and short answer, perfect!

Comment: @CactusCake I added that to my answer.

Comment: I'm confused, because it appears some red's are outlines rather than filled, and there are black elements both filled and non-filled...

Comment: @Trotski94 The description in this answer is not quite correct. In this chart, color indicates change from previous close (green for up, red for down, black for flat), while hollow indicates close above open and filled indicates close below open.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't be simpler:

means there was a ***large range*** of prices that day.